# How can I model a binary outcome with four-level predictors?

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I have 63,419 level-1 observations and 329 level-2, 138 level-3 and 21 level-4 clusters. Thus,

1) I have an average of only 2.4 level-3 clusters for each level-2 one, and of 6.6 level-4 clusters for each level-3 one. Also, I have only 21 highest-level clusters.

2) This also implies that my clusters are not balanced.

I see an obvious problem of statistical power with such small numbers. Here:

([pdf](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/track/pdf/10.1186/1471-2288-7-34?site=bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com))

it is found that at least 100 clusters, with a size of at least 50 are required to have unbiased (or only slightly biased) parameter estimates.

I see that, in general, such calculations for adequate sample-size relate to 2-level models: I don't know whether they also apply to higher-level models, or things could be worse for them. In any case, it is clear that, with my data, I have a problem.

3) I also have predictors at all levels (5 at level-1, 2 at level-2, 4 at level-3, 4 at level-4) so I can't turn to a fixed-effect model.

4) Moreover, I wonder whether the fact that I'm using a population, so groups are not selected at random (but all included):

([pdf](http://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol10-1/p013/p013.pdf))

makes a random-effect model unfit in my case.

5) I have also thought about simplifying my model to a one with clustered standard errors (CSEs), however I found:

([pdf](http://pdf.usaid.gov/pdf_docs/Pnacq362.pdf))

that the suggestion (and also typical software implementation) is to only allow for highest-level CSEs, that I find very counter-intuitive because I couldn't control for level-2 and level-3 clustering.

How can I build a sensible model without ignoring same-cluster correlation and testing for the effect of (at least some) contextual variables?

Comment: Could you include several rows of your data for more clarity?

Comment: Thank you, Alexey. I have no idea how to include my dataset.  I have it in Stata now. Of course, I can transform it in Excel if needed. However, I don't know how it could be of help.

Comment: I guess it would be helpful to just look at several top rows from your data to get an idea of the data problem complexity.